# Why doesn't NDEigenSystem give smooth eigenfunctions?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I'm looking for smooth solutions of the 1D Helmholtz equation

$\left[\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+k_{0}^{2}\epsilon(x)\right]\phi=0$

with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, where the permittivity $\epsilon(x)$ is step function. I want to use the eigensystem command in Mathematica but when I run the following code, I get a fundamental eigensolution which has discontinuous derivative:

```
Epsilon[x_] = Piecewise[{{10, x < 0.1}, {1, x >= 0.1}}];
Plot[Evaluate[
  NDEigensystem[{-u''[x]/Epsilon[x], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
    1][[2]]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

One can solve by hand the differential equation in the two regions giving four unknowns (two in each region). We therefore require four conditions to solve the system uniquely. The Dirichlet boundary conditions are two of these. Continuity and a continuous derivative at the step change in permittivity should each provide a further condition giving four overall. I therefore expected a smooth solution, but I only get a continuous solution. Why is Mathematica not doing this, and how does one impose this (instead of what it's actually doing)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do not forget about `DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]`, this requires 2 constants from 4. The other two provide continuity.

Comment: Do you mean the symbolic solution with `DEigensystem` (given in the title) or is this about `NDEigenssyste` (used in the code)?

Comment: I have a package that may help you find these, which suggests that the first few eigenvalues are around $9.137, 25.958, 53.9325$.

Comment: Can you share the solution you are expecting?